# Trigger "click" on Span "Add Cc:" in Gmail

Tags: jquery, gmail, userscripts

In order to show the input field for a cc: adress I am trying to automatically click the "Add Cc" span in gmail from a chrome extension.

The span looks like this:

```
<span id=":25j" class="el" role="link" tabindex="2">Add Cc</span>
```

It has no event listeners/onclick defined as far as I can tell.

I tried

```
   $('iframe').each(function() {
    $('span:contains("Add Cc")',this.contentDocument).first().click();
   }
```

and

```
   $('iframe').each(function() {
     $('span:contains("Add Cc")').first().trigger( jQuery.Event("click"));
   }
```

UPDATE: in fact the spans are inside an iframe.

Can somebody give me a pointer how to trigger a click on these spans?

Is there some way I could observe/record what events get fired when I manually click on the link?

**UPDATE:** Thanks @veeTrain for pointing out how to set breakpoints in Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you trying to focus into the 'add cc:' input? Because you can do .focus() instead of .click() in that case.

Let me know if this is fine for you, in that case I will post it as my answer.

Comment: @Mosselman I am trying to open/show the input field for cc address, focus() doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: @Mosselman When composing an e-mail using Google Mail there isn't a `CC` input box by default, you have to click a span (that's styled to look like a hyperlink) with the text 'Add CC' in order to make it appear. It's clicking on that span that they want to automate.

Comment: If you look at the DOM you will see that the input is already there. You should be able to get it to show up with:
    jQuery('textarea[name=cc]').parent().parent().show()
The problem is however that it seems as if I can't test this from my console due to the way that the page is setup in. They use iframes, etc. Maybe you CAN get to it from a plugin?

Comment: @Mosselman this did the trick please add it as an answer. It's not working from the console because everything is inside an iframe

Comment: @Cilvic glad I could help. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the DOM you will see that the input is already there. You should be able to get it to show up with:

```
jQuery('textarea[name=cc]').parent().parent().show()
```

However it seems as if I can't test this from my console due to the way that the page is setup. They use iframes, etc. Maybe you CAN get to it from a plugin?

You might also try to find a better way to get at the parent element rather than using `parent().parent()`, I would, but I can't test this out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would click the Cc via code; your attempts look good to me.

You could use Chrome's Developer Tools to watch and learn lots about events that occur. You can pause, break, step through and more watching variables and looking at the call stack.

However, you probably will want to override the click event in your scripting first and then break on that.

(untested)

```
$('span:contains("Add Cc")').click(function() {
    // Set a break point here and then when a click on Cc is
    // generated, you should be able to investigate
});
```

Have you made sure to include jQuery manually? gmail doesn't appear to have it loaded by default.
Try typing jQuery in the inspector to find out.
Also, you could try to find your element by other means such as by id if the span:contains doesn't seem to work for you.

Comment: No problem; glad you got your answer

Comment: I mentioned you in the question, but I feel @mosselman gave the answer to really solve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Definitely! That's the answer I was glad you got